# Vortex Mod Manager Unable to find SkyrimSE.exe

Tags: wine, directory, steam

I've recently installed Steam via Ubuntu Software center and installed Skyrim SE and Skyrim Script Extender. When I ran the install from Steam, it installed the SkyrimSE.exe to the directory ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Skyrim Special Edition However, Vortex is looking for the SkyrimSE.exe in ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps.

Therefore, I'm trying to find steps to manually route Vortex to the correct folder, because when I try to map it I'm unable navigate to the Home Directory. My options in vortex are as follows:
(C:)
(Z:)

Answer (score 0):

The first time I tried Vortex under Wine, I used symlinks from my Wine Vortex install to the Steam common directory and from steam common to wine vortex install directory. It is a real pain if you are new to Ubuntu but it worked. That is it worked once I got Vortex to not crash on loading. Reacquainting myself with Linux Distros happens every couple of years. My OS is now POP Ubuntu from system 76. Here is the link to doing it that way:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/hxt7gx/guide_use_nexus_vortex_or_another_mod_manager_in/

Anyway I will be trying out the following next:

The reported easiest way is to install the Windows version of Steam under Wine that way Vortex, or almost any Windows mod manager, will not have a problem finding your games. Check this out.....

https://rootgamer.com/how-to/install-steam-windows-ver-on-linux